# How to get all the missing information when debugging with gdb

Tags: c#, debugging, mono, gdb

I have this call trace when debugging a C# application running on mono with gdb:

```
Thread 104 (Thread 0x7f37edec8700 (LWP 16281)):
#0  pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:239
#1  0x00000000006e3ba6 in mono_os_cond_timedwait (cond=0x184a1f8, mutex=0x184a1d0, timeout_ms=9435) at ../../mono/utils/mono-os-mutex.h:216
#2  0x00000000006e55d9 in mono_w32handle_timedwait_signal_naked (cond=0x184a1f8, mutex=0x184a1d0, timeout=9435, poll=0, alerted=0x7f37edec6ed0) at w32handle.c:956
#3  0x00000000006e58b1 in mono_w32handle_timedwait_signal_handle (handle=0x401, timeout=9435, poll=0, alerted=0x7f37edec6ed0) at w32handle.c:1071
#4  0x00000000006e5ca0 in mono_w32handle_wait_one (handle=0x401, timeout=9435, alertable=1) at w32handle.c:1190
#5  0x00000000006e5d60 in mono_w32handle_wait_multiple (handles=0x7f37edec7318, nhandles=1, waitall=0, timeout=9435, alertable=1) at w32handle.c:1224
#6  0x00000000006b6b48 in mono_wait_uninterrupted (thread=0x7f37f15a03c0, numhandles=1, handles=0x7f37edec7318, waitall=0, ms=9435, error=0x7f37edec7320) at threads.c:1892
#7  0x00000000006b6f26 in ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_internal (handle=0x401, ms=9435) at threads.c:2017
#8  0x0000000040461366 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f37edec7410 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f37e0002190 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f37edec7370 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007f37edec7410 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007f37edec73c0 in ?? ()
#14 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I would like to eliminate all the unknowns (these parts `in ?? ()`), mainly because I see a CPU pegging issue in the code the question marks is all I see, e.g.:

```
Thread 100 (Thread 0x7f37aad33700 (LWP 10397)):
#0  0x00000000406adc9f in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f37aad31ad0 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007f37ed69eed8 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007f37dd85b250 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f37dd85b230 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f37ed69eed8 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f37dd85b250 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f37f11812a0 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007f37ed69eec0 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f37ed3405e0 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f37ed6aaa18 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f37f11812a0 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007f37f117c4f8 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007f37aad31b60 in ?? ()
#14 0x00000000406bb2c8 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007f37f11812a0 in ?? ()
#16 0x00007f37f11812a0 in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000000098 in ?? ()
#18 0x00007f37f117f890 in ?? ()
#19 0x00007f37f117e770 in ?? ()
#20 0x00007f37f117f330 in ?? ()
#21 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

**Question:** based on the low memory addresses, like `0x00007f37f117f330` I would presume that this is user-space code. I have the mono installed in debug mode = w/o the compiler optimizations (`CFLAGS=O0`). Does this mean that this is not mono code where the function is stuck, but the application that mono is hosting? What would be the definitive way to proove it?

My way is this - but is this really correct?:

```
[root@ct1rid5 log]# cat /proc/16281/maps | grep 7f37f1
7f37f0600000-7f37f1401000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f37f1401000-7f37f1405000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 658927                     /usr/lib/xstream/Rid/CompanyName.Configuration.Connection.dll
7f37f1405000-7f37f1423000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 151953                     /root/mono-debug-install-dir/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
7f37f1423000-7f37f151b000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 151943                     /root/mono-debug-install-dir/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
7f37f151b000-7f37f1520000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 658933                     /usr/lib/xstream/Rid/CompanyName.Logging.dll
7f37f1520000-7f37f1524000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 152104                     /root/mono-debug-install-dir/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceProcess/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.pdb
7f37f1524000-7f37f1530000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 152103                     /root/mono-debug-install-dir/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceProcess/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll
7f37f1530000-7f37f15b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f37f15b2000-7f37f15b4000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 658917                     /usr/lib/xstream/Rid/ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net.dll
7f37f15b4000-7f37f15b8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f37f15b8000-7f37f15ba000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 658941                     /usr/lib/xstream/Rid/CompanyName.Threading.dll
7f37f15ba000-7f37f15bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f37f15bc000-7f37f15bd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f37f15bd000-7f37f1fbd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f37f1fbd000-7f37f7e52000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 534745                     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either print the method name for each address
using

```
p mono_pmip(0x0000000040461366)
p mono_pmip(0x00007f37edec7410)
```

etc...

Or

To print all method names, put below code in ".gdbinit" of your home directory. Then you can call `mono_backtrace` command..

```
define mono_backtrace
 select-frame 0
 set $i = 0
 while ($i < $arg0)
   set $foo = (char*) mono_pmip ($pc)
   if ($foo)
     printf "#%d %p in %s\n", $i, $pc, $foo
   else
     frame
   end
   up-silently
   set $i = $i + 1
 end
end
```

I found the above information in mono project documentation 
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/

Comment: Still missing a lot of information: but this is the output: https://p.defau.lt/?cO3Gc1mGfxgyA9L_ParZEA - Question: the stack trace does not have any mono functions in it, does it mean that mono somehow lost control of this thread? Any other further debugging tips? Thanks

Comment: Did you use debug Libraries??

Comment: I do to a large extent - I installed: `debuginfo-install mono-core-5.4.0.201-0.xamarin.1.epel6.x86_64`, when the thread executes normally I see a normal stack trace, like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/syG8KveK - however when the bug is present, I see this: https://p.defau.lt/?cO3Gc1mGfxgyA9L_ParZEA - I think the function calls that are not visible are from the service that mono is running (hosted code) ? Do you think that could be the case?

Comment: Additionally, this is the gdb output when it attaches: https://pastebin.com/raw/EqucnHU3 - seems like all the required debug libs are present.